# Is it possible to interact with a deployed contract (not mine) with Remix Solidity IDE?

Tags: remix

I know that I can call methods or send transactions with `web3.js`.
But, is it possible to interact with a deployed contract (not mine), like golem, status, etc.. with Remix Solidity IDE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Interacting off-chain (web3js)**

Yes, you will need to fetch ABI from a deployed contract. Popular contracts usually publish their code on sites like Etherscan. For example, here you can find a source code and ABI for [Golem contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa74476443119A942dE498590Fe1f2454d7D4aC0d#code) which is deployed to `0xa74476443119A942dE498590Fe1f2454d7D4aC0d`.

Then you may create an instance of `contract` object using `web3js` to interact with the deployed code at the given address:

```
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(FETCHED_ABI);

// instantiate by address
var contractInstance = MyContract.at(DEPLOYED_ADDRESS);
```

Here you can read more about [interacting with contracts](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract).

**Interacting on-chain (Remix)**

In your contract can inline interface with the methods of Golem contract that you want to use:

```
contract GolemToken {
  function totalSupply() external constant returns (uint256){}
}
```

Then you simply cast an address to this contract and call a method:

```
GolemToken token = GolemToken(ADDRESS);
uint supply = token.totalSuppy();
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. I know I can interact with a deployed contract with web3.js. Sorry but I realize that I've made a mistake in my question. What I wuol like to know is if I can interact with a deployed contract using the Remix Solidity IDE (with Metamask). I edited the question.

Comment: I've edited the answer. I hope it helps now.

Answer (score 2):

You could also compile the source code of the contract you want to interact with using Remix, then go to the deploy & run tab and load the contract from its address.